# Angularjs goes into infinite loop while firing $http function

Tags: angularjs

My app goes into infinite loop while firing $http get method inside a function

In my controller I am using POST and getting data from API after authorization and displaying it.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ctrl1', function($scope, $http) {
   $http({
         url: 'url',
         method: "POST",
         data: 'postData',
         headers: {
            'Authorization': 'value'
         }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
         $scope.hotels = response.data;
      });

   $scope.imagePath = function(id) {
      console.info(id);
      if (id) {
         $http({
               method: 'GET',
               url: 'url=' + id
            })
            .then(function(response) {
               var imgdata = response.data;
               console.info(imgdata);
               var imgdata1 = imgdata.data.image_name;
               return "url" + imgdata1;
            });


      }
   };
});
```

In my img ng-src I have to call data from another API from the key exterior_image which I am passing in my function but it goes into an infinite loop. Also I know I have to use angular forEach in imgdata1.

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl1'>
   <select ng-options='item as item.hotel_name for item in hotels.data' ng-model='hotel'></select>
   <h1>{{hotel.hotel_name}}</h1>
   <p>{{hotel.hotel_description}}</p>
   <img ng-src="{{imagePath(hotel.exterior_image)}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Use `ng-init` to set the `src` property of the hotel instead of putting a function in `ng-src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl1', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.current_Hotel = {
        hotel_name: "Default Value Here",
        hotel_description: "Default Value Here",
        exterior_image: "Default id here",
        image_url: "Default url here"
    };

    $http({
        url: 'url',
        method: "POST",
        data: 'postData',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'value'
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.hotels = response.data;
            });       

    $scope.selectHotel = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'url=' + $scope.current_Hotel.exterior_image
        }).then(function (response) {
                    var imgdata = response.data;
                    var imgdata1 = imgdata.data.image_name;
                    $scope.current_Hotel.image_url = "url" + imgdata1;
                });
    };


});
```

and this:

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl1'>
    <select ng-options='item as item.hotel_name for item in hotels.data' ng-model='current_Hotel'></select>       
    <h1>{{current_Hotel.hotel_name}}</h1>
    <p>{{current_Hotel.hotel_description}}</p>
     <img ng-src="{{current_Hotel.image_url}}">
</div>
```